# Unable to login after db upgrade

Tags: postgresql, logins

I upgraded postgresql from 8.4.2 to 12.3. I created a dump of the db from the old version, and restored into the new version.
The port for the new version is 5532. The old one uses 5432. After I restore the dump, I check that the service is running for the new version, and the server is listening on port 5532 for all interfaces.
I even copy the pg_hba.conf entries from the old version to the new version. But instead of "password" I change all the entries to "md5" because this is a newer version. After changes, I reload pg_hba.conf.
However, when we test access to the new db now, it does not work. It fails with error :

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again. Reason : Could not
> get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for
> host "192.168.130.209", user "app_support", database "bosupportdb"

Postgres ports :

```
[root@reportv2 data]# ss -tulpn | grep postgres
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:5432                  *:*                   users:(("postgres",pid=3454,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:5532                  *:*                   users:(("postgres",pid=4763,fd=3))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::5432                 :::*                   users:(("postgres",pid=3454,fd=4))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::5532                 :::*                   users:(("postgres",pid=4763,fd=4))
[root@reportv2 data]#
```

These are my pg_hba.conf entries :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host   all              all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.130.0/24        md5
#host   all             all             192.168.8.0/24          md5
host    all             all             192.168.90.8/32         md5
host    all             all             192.168.8.175/32        md5
host    all             all             192.168.112.0/23        md5
```

Please help me resolve this. I am clueless.

Comment: Maybe you copied the `pg_hba.conf` file to the wrong location. If you can log in as the superuser, you can use `show hba_file;` to verify which files is used

Comment: It's showing the correct path : postgres=# show hba_file;
               hba_file
--------------------------------------
 /usr/local/pgsql123/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

postgres=#

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the HBA rules that PostgreSQL is actually *using* are the ones you *expect*:

```
select * 
from pg_hba_file_rules 
where type = 'host' 
order by line_number ;
```

Check the **error** column for anything amiss with the file syntax.

Comment: The error column is empty.for all.

Comment: So the file is valid.  That's good.  
Do the rules listed /match/ those in your pg_hba.conf?  
Is PostgreSQL looking in the right place (what's the "-D" argument on the postmaster process). 
Enable "connection" logging in postgresql.conf and try again.  You may get more information in the postgres error log. 
Add a rule specifically for this machine ("host all all 192.168.130.209/32 md5").  See if that works.  
As a /really/ long shot, change the authentication on that rule to use "trust".  If that works, then it may be a problem with the password (but I'd be surprised).

Comment: Yes, the rules match with pg_hba.conf. The -D arg is the data dir which is /usr/local/pgsql123/data. I saw in the old version's postgresql.conf that the max_connections is 200. In the new version it was 100. Could this be the reason?

Comment: I just checked, and log connections is not on in the new version.